# send arraylist through the socket

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I have a socket (the server and client side).
In the server side i have an arrayList . Each time that a new user   connect,  i add it to the arrayList. Then i send the arraylist  to everyone .
But when the client receives the arrayList:

```
First Client 
[user1]

Second Client
[user1,user2]

Third Client
[user1,user2,user3]
```

But if i send it to string , receives correctly.

I used ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream

```
//Server Side
public void tellEveryOne(){
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        try{
            ObjectOutputStream oos = (ObjectOutputStream) it.next();
            oos.writeObject(namesMachines);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}

//Client Side

public void run(){
        Object obj;
        try{
            while((obj=ois.readObject())!=null){
                castObject(obj);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){}

}
```

Comment: please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`, or call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`. Otherwise objects that have already been transmitted are not retransmitted.

Comment: Ok I see . I only need to reset the output ,right?   The input is not necessary

Comment: @FearDark There is no `ObjectInputStream.reset()` method.

Comment: Thank you !! . It works . You saved me

Answer (score -1):

You can send Arraylist through socket interface using ObjectOutputStream and read arraylist at the client side using ObjectInputStream as long as The object you are putting in the list and sending implements the Serializable interface. String implements Serializable so youre good.

Comment: Yes . I send it like this . But the first client only receive the first element , and the second only receive two elements . But i dont why .

Comment: You are retaining the old copy of the arraylist. When only user1 connects, the server sends back an arraylist [user1] but when user2 connects, it receives an arraylist [user1, user2] but user1 still retains the old arraylist [user1] . Make sure that you overwrite the arraylist every time you receive an object from the server.

Comment: I post my code . What do you think ?